# Pretérito indefinido vs pretérito imperfecto: ¿"estaba" or "estuve un poco enfermo el fin de semana pasado"?

Tags: gramática, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

When I want to say the following in Spanish:

> I was a little bit sick last weekend.

Do I use the pretérito indefinido or imperfecto?
e.g.

> Estuve un poco enfermo el fin de semana pasado.

Vs

> Estaba un poco enfermo el fin de semana pasado.

It feels like I'm describing a situation in the past (imperfecto?), but `el fin de semana pasado` feels like an indefinido. I was sick, but that's completely over...

How do I know what to use?

Comment: Both are fine. Depends on the context around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted `estuve` indicates the action is over. `estaba` indicates the action is over or *not*.
In this context is totally irrelevant which form you use. 
I personally would use `estaba` which is a much more simpler and common form to indicate a single past action. Specially when you don't include another past action in the same context that needs to be prioritize by time.

Comment: This makes sense to me.  People tend to use "estaba" is situations like this where the existence or nonexistence of a precise endpoint is fuzzy.  "Estuve" is an unusual verb.  It's not used nearly as often as something like "hablé," because "estaba" is used incredibly often to set a scene, in preparation for reporting a time-defined action with the preterite.  For example, "Estaba enfermo cuando llegó tu carta, por lo que no la pude contestar hasta ahora."

Answer (score 1):

Saying "I was a little bit sick last weekend" has a definite end. Therefore, you should use the pretérito indefinido.

Comment: How come? You can still be sick.

Comment: The English sentence "I was a little bit sick last weekend" implies that the speaker is no longer sick. If it was an ongoing sickness, the sentence would have been: "I have been sick since last weekend."

Comment: No longer still sick at what point?  If he says I was sick and then describes what he was doing as a result of so being, it needs to be imperfect.  You can't determine preterite/imperfect generally without more context.  That's what fedorqui was getting at.  If I say "estaba" or "estuve" enfermo on the weekend, there is going to be the same implication that I am no longer sick — just that with estuve it's guaranteed that I'm not (unless I caught a different illness).